# Why .ajaxComplete has to be attached to document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saw this "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document." in the jQuery document, so I'm wondering why it has to be attached to the document. As I tried, it works fine if I attach it to window or somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ajaxComplete` isn't really an event, it's entirely synthetic within jQuery, and doesn't relate to any specific element. In previous versions, jQuery didn't care where you attached it, but that leads to implementation complexity. Rather than having to fire the event hither and yon, the developers decided to start the process of only firing the event on `document`, presumably to simplify the implementation.

Comment: That last _presumably_ makes me think this question is going to result in more opinion than fact.

Comment: @Mathletics: Perhaps. I went off looking for a commit message or issue I could cite, but reached my time limit on it without finding something I could point to.